# Bootstrap file upload on Lotus Notes web app

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am submitting my bootstrap form using jquery `.serialize()` method without file upload control and everything is OK.After adding bootstrap file upload control I realized 
.`serialize()` doesn't send attachments.Is there any solution to add file upload control without doing,

> - ?Readform approach
> - without re-writing submission module from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve the same with something like,

```
var formData = new FormData($form[0]);

$.ajax({  
         type: "POST", 
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         enctype:$form.attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ),
         url: $(e.target).attr('action'),  
         data: formData,  
         success: function( data ) { }   
}).then(function() {
        //Further conditions                
})
```

> Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I am using almost exactly that code, and it works perfectly.
The only difference is that the POST URL returns JSON indicating success or failure and then redirect the uers to different pages based on that:

Comment: @Karl-HenryMartinsson, Just curious is there any browser compatibility you have encountered with above code? So far I have tested working fine with Firefox and IE-11.

Comment: No, since it is jQuery it should not be any browser issues, as long as you use a browser supported by the version of jQuery you are using. Use jQuery 1.x if you have users with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I am using almost exactly the same code as Rishi posted, with the addition of checking the JSON returned by the HTTP POST, and redirecting the users's browser based on the response (success or failure):

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/upload',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == true) {
            window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
        } else {
            var errorMsg = data.message;
            window.location.replace("Failure.html?errormsg=" + errorMsg);
        }
    }
});
```